# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined JS

Tags: javascript

Есть `JSON`  и хочу пробежаться по свойствам элементов:

```
var res = JSON.stringify(_o);
var obj = JSON.parse(res);

for (var pos = 0; pos <= obj.response.length; pos++) {
   var str = obj.response[pos].id;
   console.log(str);
};
```

Но в консоли выскакивает ошибка `TypeError`:

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

Подскажите почему?
Такое  свойство `id` точно есть внутри `JSON`.

```
{ id: 40,
  first_name: 'Олег',
  last_name: 'Чередников',
  sex: 2,
  bdate: '30.12.1984' }
{ id: 41,
  first_name: 'Владислав',
  last_name: 'Миллер',
  sex: 2,
  bdate: '3.2.1986' }
{ id: 42,
  first_name: 'Сергей',
  last_name: 'Маркин',
  sex: 2,
  bdate: '20.4' }
```

Comment: Без примера того, что парсится в объект, помочь не предоставляется возможным.
Что в `_o`? Странно, правда, сериализовать объект и тут же его восстанавливать.
Ошибка говорит о том что у `undefined` нет свойства `id`. Т.е. нет в `response` ничего с таким ключом.

Comment: @TheDoctor { id: 40,
  first_name: 'Олег',
  last_name: 'Чередников',
  sex: 2,
  bdate: '30.12.1984' }
{ id: 41,
  first_name: 'Владислав',
  last_name: 'Миллер',
  sex: 2,
  bdate: '3.2.1986' }
{ id: 42,
  first_name: 'Сергей',
  last_name: 'Маркин',
  sex: 2,
  bdate: '20.4' }

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос.

Comment: @TheDoctor добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может надо сделать так

```
"1":{ id: 40, first_name: 'Олег', last_name: 'Чередников', sex: 2, bdate: '30.12.1984' } "2":{ id: 41, first_name: 'Владислав', last_name: 'Миллер', sex: 2, bdate: '3.2.1986' } "3":{ id: 42, first_name: 'Сергей', last_name: 'Маркин', sex: 2, bdate: '20.4' }
```

Или вместо `obj.response[pos].id;` сделать `obj.response[Object.keys(obj.response)[pos]].id;`

И к стати наверно лучше сделать `obj.response.length - 1`

А в идеале конечно хочется увидеть содержимое obj.response

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка:

```
for (var pos = 0; pos <= obj.response.length; pos++) {
```

Должно быть либо `pos < obj.response.length`, либо `pos <= obj.response.length - 1`. Так как нумерация в массивах начинается с нуля, а не с единицы, индекс посленего элемента массива равен `obj.response.length - 1`, а вы в цикле пытаетесь получить элемент массива с индексом `obj.response.length`, которого не существует.

Answer (score 0):

> for (var pos = 0; pos **<=** obj.response.length; pos++) {

for (var pos = 0; pos **<** obj.response.length; pos++) {